# How do I use the "cl-position" function accurately in clisp?

Tags: lisp, common-lisp, clisp

I am trying to use cl-position in clisp, however, whenever I try to run the code, I get the following error:

```
    Prinayas-MacBook-Pro:~ pchoubey$ clisp project1.lisp
    *** - SYSTEM::%EXPAND-FORM:
          (PRINT (CL-POSITION "bar" '("foo" "bar" "baz") :TEST 'EQUAL)) should be
          a lambda expression
```

Why is this happening and how can I get this code to run properly? For reference, here is my code:

```
(defun answer-ynq()
  (setq ROBOT '(IS_A_ROBOT ROBBIE))
  (loop for x in ROBOT
    do(
       (print (cl-position "bar" '("foo" "bar" "baz") :test 'equal))
    ))

  (setq KB (make-hash-table :test 'equal))

(setf (gethash '(IS_A_ROBOT ROBBIE) KB)'T)
(setf (gethash '(IS_A_PERSON BOB) KB) 'T)
(setf (gethash '(IS_CLEVER ROBBIE) KB) 'T)
(setf (gethash '(OWNS ALICE ROBBIE) KB) 'T)
)
(answer-ynq)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**first we need to make the code better formatted and indented**

```
(defun answer-ynq ()
  (setq ROBOT '(IS_A_ROBOT ROBBIE))
  (loop for x in ROBOT
        do ((print (cl-position "bar" '("foo" "bar" "baz")
                                :test 'equal))))

  (setq KB (make-hash-table :test 'equal))

  (setf (gethash '(IS_A_ROBOT ROBBIE) KB) T)
  (setf (gethash '(IS_A_PERSON BOB) KB)   T)
  (setf (gethash '(IS_CLEVER ROBBIE) KB)  T)
  (setf (gethash '(OWNS ALICE ROBBIE) KB) T))

(answer-ynq)
```

**The actual error: wrong parentheses**

```
((print (cl-position "bar" '("foo" "bar" "baz")
                     :test 'equal)))
```

One can't put parentheses around a function call like that. Generally parentheses are not optional grouping characters, but they provide essential syntactic structure.

It has to be:

```
(print (cl-position "bar" '("foo" "bar" "baz")
                    :test 'equal))
```

If one wants more than one form in such a `loop` expression one has two basic options:

```
(loop ...
      do (do-this foo bar)
         (do-that foo baz))
```

or

```
(loop ...
      do (progn
           (do-this foo bar)
           (do-that foo baz)))
```

`progn` is a *special operator*. The enclosed forms are evaluated one by one and the last result value is returned.

**more problems are lurking**

`ROBOT` and `KB` are undefined variables. If you want to introduce additional local variables, one can use `let` and `let*`.

`cl-position` is an undefined function in Common Lisp. It is actually called `position`. In Common Lisp the standard function never have a prefix `cl-`. They have this prefix in Emacs Lisp, which lacks namespaces for function names and uses the prefix as an ugly hack. Common Lisp has namespaces for function names (called *packages*) and thus functions like `position` don't need a name prefix. With the namespace, the name in Common Lisp is `cl:position` or longer `common-lisp:position`. Most of the time one can just write `position`.