# How to create a list of lists in lisp?

Tags: lisp, common-lisp, clisp

I am trying to run code in common lisp, but it keeps giving me the following error:

```
*** - SYSTEM::%EXPAND-FORM: (SETF (NTH X NUMS) 0) should be a lambda
      expression
```

What am I doing wrong? I am pretty new to lisp, and here is my code:

```
(defun answer-ynq()

  (setq nums '(13 15 19 33))
  (setq numsstuff '())

  (loop for x from 1 to 4
    do (progn(
          (setf (nth x nums) 0) 
          (append numstuff nums)
          )))

  (print numstuff) 


)

(answer-ynq)
```

Also, is this the right way to create a list out of lists? I need numsstuff to be a list of lists in this way, where if I give in a list of objects (13 15 19 33), I get an output that is the following list of lists: 
((0 15 19 33) (13 0 19 33) (13 15 0 33) (13 15 19 0))

Thank you so much!

Comment: You again have a added parentheses pair. (progn ( ...)) should be (progn ...).

Comment: Here is a good introductory book for Common Lisp: https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~dst/LispBook/book.pdf

Comment: Same error message and same cause as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60767680/ .

Answer (score 1):

```
CL-USER > (loop for i below 4
                collect (loop for e in '(13 15 19 33)
                              for j from 0
                              when (= i j) collect 0 else collect e))

((0 15 19 33) (13 0 19 33) (13 15 0 33) (13 15 19 0))
```